# New to Python, Trying to create a small python script to extract password from a password generation internal website that uses javascripts and forms

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

So we have an internal website which generates password for our privileged user. I want to automate that function by using python.

So this is how the website is:

- Main Page: Enter your credentials (Site specific) - > Press Login
  button

  - The submit button has j_security_check at the back end.

```
- loginUrl = 'https://internal.website.local/self/j_security_check'
resLogin = session.post(loginUrl, data = {'j_username': 'myusername' ,'j_password': 'mypassword', 'submitbut': 'Log In','command': 'submit','browserDate': '1576177981845','browserOffset': '240','browserTimeZone_2005': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2006': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2007': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2008': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2009': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2010': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2011': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2012': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2013': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2014': '0:240','browserTimeZone_2015': '0:240'})
```

- I saw in the post request on the website that it takes a huge number of borwserDates & browserTimezone values, however, even if I keep these contant day in and day out things work fine.
- At this point login is successful. `Have achieved this part`

Second Page after Login:
      - After login we have a lot of links on the page. We use the page called UseCredential.do

```
MainCredential = 'https://internal.website.local/self/UseCredential.do'
CredentialDo = session.get(MainCredential, verify=False)
```

- At this point, i have successfully polled the UseCredential.do page.
- This page has 2 boxes a search button
- Usually we leave the boxes empty and press search button.
- This search button submits a form at the backend for which the code is

```
<input type="button" name="searchButton" value="Search" onclick="return submitForm('UseCredentialForm','search');" onmouseover="onMouseOverButtonHandler(this);" onmouseout="onMouseOutButtonHandler(this);" onblur="onMouseOutButtonHandler(this);" onfocus="onMouseOverButtonHandler(this);" id="searchButton" class="button button-primary " alt="Search">

Furthermore it also a script

<script>
    function onKeyPress(e) {
        if(e && e.keyCode === 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            submitForm('UseCredentialForm','search');
        }
    }
</script>
```

1. Looking at the debugs I was able to see that the following is submitted at the time of Search Button press. So executed the script using this

```
CredentialDo2 = session.post(MainCredential, data = {'searchResourceCondInput':'','searchCredentialCondInput':'','command': 'search','linkRow': ''})
```

2. Till this part I am successful and if I print CredentialDo2.text I can see that the search result is there.
   --------This is where I cannot proceed further, becuase the post data is only available in CredentialDo2 and I don't know how to proceed further.
   ---The next steps are:
3. Click on the result which is always the same name MyUserName2, which has the following code at the back

```
                                            <div class="tableCellContent" title="MyUserName2">
                                                <a
                                                    href="javascript:submitTableLink(&#039;UseCredentialForm&#039;,&#039;selectSharedAccount&#039;,&#039;a73e0a84_0&#039;)"
                                                ><span class="pim-credential-name">MyUserName2</span>
                                                <span class=""></span>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            </td>
```

OBSERVATION: The value in the javascript a73e0a84_0 at the end changes always. And I can see this value is passed on in the post.

1. Once we click the MyUserName2, I get the page where I have to type
   in the textbox and the press submit.
2. Once submit, it will send to a new page where I click View Password to get the new password. This ViewPassword button also
   executes a javascript. I will need help two get the password. I will share more code once I reach there.

Kindly note that in all this the link above in the address bar does not change from 'https://internal.website.local/self/UseCredential.do'

Any and all help will be much appreciated. 
This is my first programming with Python so please bear with me.

Comment: No suggestions :(